# Does an IE6-compatible alternative to the Nivo Slider exist?

Tags: javascript, gallery, nivo-slider

Does an alternative to the [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) exist? I need a slider that is compatible with IE6.

Answer (score 2):

First result in [google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=alternative+for+nivo+slider): http://www.cvul.com/scripts/coin-slider-jquery-image-slider-compatible-with-old-browsers/

Answer (score 2):

Here you are: http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/ - The AnythingSlider works great in IE6.

Comment: Great stuff, but note that this has some quirks in IE6.